# Google Cloud Functions user_id vs userID

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am running google cloud functions on top of a firestore database.  For some of my functions the `context` which contains info on the user who caused the execution to occur is store in the context as `user_id` and other time is stored as `userID`.

Example 1:

```
Context! { eventId: 'c5d21684-d929-4522-93b8-9defa8efc523-0',
  eventType: 'google.firestore.document.create',
  notSupported: {},
  params: 
   { date: '1567551802.9012709',
     user_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
  resource: 
   { service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/longpathxxxxxxxx' },
  timestamp: '2019-09-03T23:03:23.048799Z' }
```

Example 2:

```
incredible { eventId: 'af75b0a0-c612-466e-9fb5-5970be1e23fa-0',
  eventType: 'google.firestore.document.create',
  notSupported: {},
  params: 
   { date: '1567552527.172058',
     userID: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy' },
  resource: 
   { service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/pathlongxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
  timestamp: '2019-09-03T23:15:27.309423Z' }
```

Is it something to do with an update or what?
Any ideas would be helpful because as far as I know `context` is created by Cloud Functions and I don't directly control what is in context.

The only code preceding is as such

```
exports.funcName = functions.firestore.document('path').onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

`path` is multiple things, tho I don't see how that could make a difference having the exact string.
It goes `collection/document/collection/document`.  I have lots of functions.

Comment: Do you have the code you used to write those values into Firestore ?

Comment: Without seeing the code of the function, there's not much to be said.  I suspect the answer is in the function code itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson made an edit

Comment: That doesn't look like it will do anything.  Are you really just passing "path" to the function builder?  Please show the exact code.

Comment: I'm simply passing a string that is read as a path.

Comment: @DougStevenson `onCreate` is a firebase function, the exact string I input should not be the info you need to at least cite why `onCreate` is capable of providing different outputs.

Comment: The string you're passing is very important. It's defining what you see in context.params.  Just showing "path" isn't getting closer to the explanation, but I'll try to guess what you're doing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of actual code that generates the output you've shown, I'll just take a guess.  The actual code is important to see, since that's what's causing your confusion.

The `context` parameter passed to your function will have a `params` property that defines the names and values of the wildcards you define in your document path.  This is well [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters):

> Wildcard matches are extracted from the document path and stored into context.params. You may define as many wildcards as you like to substitute explicit collection or document IDs

Your first output shows context.params containing this:

```
  params: 
   { date: '1567551802.9012709',
     user_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
```

That means your function defined two wildcards in the document path, `date` and `user_id`.  They will appear in curly braces in the path.

Your second output shows this:

```
  params: 
   { date: '1567552527.172058',
     userID: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy' },
```

This means the function declared two wildcards, `date` and `userID`.  These are coming from your function's definition.  It's not something that Cloud Functions is making up.  If you don't like that the names of the parameters are different, change them to suit what you want to see among all of your functions.